# Can we use <action.NDEF_DISCOVERED> without data field?

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, ndef

How to filter all the tags with NDEF message.
I tried this

```
<intent-filter>                
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

But it works only with an aditional `<data .../>` field

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that does not work on all versions of Android.
You can filter for the `Ndef` technology using an intent filter for action `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` and an XML file with the definition, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#tech-disc for documentation.